# How do I install nano-hmac on Mac OS X?

Tags: c, macos, haskell, openssl, cabal

"nano-hmac" is a Haskell package which can normally be installed using Cabal.  However, Mac OS X has a different OpenSSL library than the one it expects, so it fails to compile bindings.

I can install the version of openssl from openssl.org, but I'm not sure how to instruct Cabal to use this instead of the Mac OS X version.

Answer (score 1):

macports has its own openssl, ghc and hs-cabal. Have you tried installing everything via macports?

Comment: I wasn't able to get a pre-compiled cabal to use macports openssl.  Hopefully this will work though.

Comment: I hope you'll not be offended by macports having right now just updated their ghc port.

Comment: I can't install it. It doesn't like my version of perl, even though I got that from macports too.  It says: checking for perl... /opt/local/bin/perl5.8 configure: error: your version of perl probably won't work, try upgrading it.

Comment: sudo port install ghc.  Here's a pastie of the output: http://www.friendpaste.com/56TvcPjhLy2jN9FBvSRrAl

Comment: just wondering if you ever managed to get this going / still interested in solving it.

Before you try anything else, you should probably try upgrading all your ports. Every time someone has a port issue that I don't, it boils down to lack of regular upgrades.

Comment: This is still a problem for me.  Anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not a Haskell developer.  (*I know, I know...*)

That said, I would recommend investigating the use of [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) which provides support for [GHC](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/browse.php?summary=haskell) as well as [openssl](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/browse.php?summary=openssl) and many (most?) common FOSS packages.